# Trying to install Fedora Silverblue, media check keeps failing at around 4%, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: fedora, boot, system-installation, disk

I am trying to boot Fedora Silverblue onto my laptop VIA a USB drive and I keep getting

```
[FAILED] Failed to start checkisomd5@dev-sdb.service - Media check on /dev/sdb.
dracut-initqueue[1423]: Job for checkisomd5@dev-sdb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
dracut-initqueue[1423]: See "systemct1 status checkisomd5@dev-sdb.service" and "journalct1 -xeu checkisomd5@dev-sdb.service" for details
dracut: FATAL: CD check failed!
dracut: Refusing to continue
```

I tried running the ISO I downloaded directly on a VM through VBox and it worked fine, any clue why I keep getting this error?

Comment: yes, your USB drive has an error about 4% in. What's the question here?

Comment: sorry if I worded it weirdly, just what I am doing wrong/what I can do to fix it, or if the installation should work fine anyways

Comment: your image on your PC for your VM is correct. Your USB media is not correct. It's not your fault - an error occurred during writing to or reading from the USB drive. Try writing the image again. If that doesn't help, you'll need a non-damaged USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

As you tested the ISO image on a VM, the ISO file is correct. (Note that you would have got checksum errors otherwise.)

Therefore, the error is in the ISO image as saved in your USB drive.

You should format the USB drive and rewrite the ISO on it. If it still gives you errors, the USB drive is faulty and you should discard it.

If you want confirmation, you can use the `badblocks` command to test bad blocks in a disk.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you still have issues, a few of solutions which gave success (I didn't determine which was the one that actually gave success) are as follows:

1. Try writing again (and with a new download if you saw the checksum failing)
2. Try the Fedora media writer from FlatHub with

   ```shell
   flatpak install app/org.fedoraproject.MediaWriter/x86_64/stable
   ```

   on another OS, in case you have an older problematic Fedora writer version.
3. In Fedora writer, try downloading your own ISO and selecting it manually
4. Try a different pen drive and/or USB port (faulty hardware?)
5. Try with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) on Windows.

Do reply back and update us if any of those work for you.